# I cannot load my templates in the Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring

I cannot access the templates I wrote under the templates folder. It will just redirect me to the Whitelabel Error Page. My structure is like this:my controller is under the `src/main/java/com.project/controller/IndexController.java` while my templates are under the `src/main/resources/templates/home.html`.My code in the controller is like this:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/vm"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public String template(Model model) {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/index"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
```

And my home.html is like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<pre>
    Hello World!
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem myself. The thing is the dependency. I did not import the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf from org.springframework.boot. The dependency is really hard to deal with in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

The default context path of the app would be `"/"` and there is neither `index.html` file is present nor a controller method for that path which is why you are seeing that `White label Error Page`. If you don't want to see that error, add the below property in your `application.properties` file then you would the `HTTP 404` Error.

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

For the below method that you have in controller:
Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body.

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/vm"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String template(Model model) {
    return "home";
}
```

Go to `http://localhost:8080/vm` this would load the `home.html` file that you have in templates folder.

Whereas for this one:

```
@RequestMapping(path = {"/index"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

You have used the annotation `@ResponseBody` which would indicate a method that the return value should be bound to the web response body, so you would see the text `Hello world` in the browser when you hit the `http://localhost:8080/index`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My problem is when I access the /index, it works well. However, when I try to access the /vm page, it will throw a whitelabel error but it's supposed to be hello world.

Answer (score 0):

you should put this method in your controller and set "myProject" as parent of all pages path.
for example to load home.html :
myProject/home

```
    @GetMapping({"/myProject" ,"/myProject/" ,"/myProject/{page}" , "/myProject/{page}/"})
public String load_page( @Nullable @PathVariable String page  ) {
    if(page == null || page.isBlank()) page = "index";
    if(page.endsWith("/")) page = page.substring(0, page.length()-1);
    return page;
}
```